# I am getting the error of Arithmetic Overflow

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Getting the error of dividing '162.0' by '0.0' and Arithmetic Overflow
Here I am providing the full MWE.Compiling with Lualatex. Earlier it compiled perfectly before I formatted my system.

```
    \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{pgfplots}
     \usepackage{adjustbox}
     \usepackage{graphicx}



       %
     \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
     \begin{tabular}{cccc}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
       ylabel={Loss Probability},
    xlabel={Buffer-Size [bits]},
    xmin=0, xmax=14000,
    ymin=0, ymax=16E-16,
   % xtick={256,512,1024},
     legend pos=north east,
    ]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,red]
plot coordinates {
    %xdn1,plk1
      (0,1.46457063425573E-15)(1417.52792188833,1.46458096146691E-15)  (2835.05584377667,1.46458096555486E-15)(4252.583765665,1.46458096649354E-15)(5670.11168755333,1.46458096725964E-15)
      (7087.63960944166,1.43183666858344E-15)   (8505.16753133,1.22606879191838E-15)(9922.69545321833,9.06217570610091E-16)   (11340.2233751067,5.78157816036983E-16)(12757.751296995,3.18387938053274E-16)
           };
     \addlegendentry{H=0.6448}

      \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue]
     plot coordinates {
   %sxdn1,splk1
    (0,1.33698141571304E-15)(1441.50423448193,1.33698201261989E-15)(2883.00846896387,1.33698201109105E-15)(4324.51270344581,1.33698201272183E-15)
     (5766.01693792774,1.33698201280592E-15)(7207.52117240968,1.30943528845524E-15)(8649.02540689161,1.12602923890446E-15)(10090.5296413735,8.3685081228585E-16)
      (11532.0338758555,5.37500860162994E-16)(12973.5381103374,2.98361672140675E-16)
           };
           \addlegendentry{H=0.5}
            \end{axis}
             \end{tikzpicture}
           &
             %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
       ylabel={Loss Probability},
    xlabel={Buffer-Size [bits]},
    xmin=0, xmax=12000,
    ymin=0, ymax=14E-16,
   % xtick={256,512,1024},
     legend pos=north east,
    ]

                   \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue]
                    plot coordinates {
             %sxdn4,splk4
              (0,1.10258554578046E-15)(1108.12247574401,1.10258554547488E-15)(2216.24495148803,1.10258554616092E-15)(3324.36742723204,1.10258554615788E-15)
         (4432.48990297606,1.06488551692328E-15)(5540.61237872007,9.43932260243838E-16)   (6648.73485446408,7.67595585423292E-16)(7756.8573302081,5.72634933511087E-16)
                (8864.97980595211,3.91901512487655E-16)(9973.10228169613,2.46053627106834E-16)
                          };
                       \addlegendentry{H=0.5}
                       \end{axis}
                     \end{tikzpicture}
                    \\ (a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
                 %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               \end{tabular}}
               \caption{}
               \end{figure}
              \end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need the extra `plot` words in pgfplots. It's a TikZ thing.

Comment: Why do you make no effort to make a real mwe? If it is too much work for you to close the environments and test if the example produces the error, why should we do it for you?

Comment: @Ulrike Now I have provided the full MWE

Comment: Your code works fine after I add the missing `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[...]` in the second table cell and change `\end{figure}` to `\end{figure*}`.

Comment: @Torbjorn Thanks but the error is same

Comment: Well, I can't really give any hints, the code works without problems  here. I have a recently updated TeX Live 2015. Perhaps the `.log` file can give some hints, can you post that?

Comment: This code is correct and it's working fine on sharelatex but I don't know why it's not working on my system and editor(WinEdt). Should I need to update MikTex?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't hurt to try updating. (By the way, as percusse said, it should be just `\addplot coordinates`, not `\addplot plot coordinates`.)

Comment: note you are missing a `%` here `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: It can hurt to update - changes can always lead to errors and actually currently one has to be careful when updating miktex as there has been quite a number of internal changes. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fair point.

Comment: @Fischer u r correct, but this time I took the risk and finally all goes well, I updated the packages, then update FNDB, and after this I compiled my code using lualatex with shell-escape as argument and it compiled the document perfectly, thanks to all for your valuable comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an update fixes the problem.